# What does this.$('.selector') do in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, scope

I see this in someone's code: `this.$('.selector')` and am curious what that does. "this" is a Backbone view. So what does prefixing "this." onto a jQuery selector, in the given context, do?

Comment: It's a shortcut for `$(this.el).find(...)` or `$('.selector',this.el)` - to scope the *queries* w.r.t. to the `el` element

Answer (score 9):

From the [doc](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar):

> **$ (jQuery or Zepto)view.$(selector)**
>
> If jQuery or Zepto is included on
> the page, each view has a $ function that runs queries scoped within
> the view's element. If you use this scoped jQuery function, you don't
> have to use model ids as part of your query to pull out specific
> elements in a list, and can rely much more on HTML class attributes.
> It's equivalent to running: `view.$el.find(selector)`

```
ui.Chapter = Backbone.View.extend({
  serialize : function() {
    return {
      title: this.$(".title").text(),
      start: this.$(".start-page").text(),
      end:   this.$(".end-page").text()
    };
  }
});
```

In short, it's used to access some elements of View with a familiar syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically limiting the search for elements with a class of `selector` to the element your View is based off of.

Comment: +1 because I didn't read your answer before posting mine, and it's pretty similar

Answer (score 0):

It's basically changing the scope of the search from `document` to `this`, which is obviously some element.

Comment: indeed, you will more commonly see it as $('.selector', this)